# Simple try/finally vs. try/catch

Tags: php, try-catch, php-5.3, php-5.5

With a simple function such as:

```
function hello( $var )
{
    try
    {
        // do something with $var which may or may not throw an exception
        return $var;
    }
    finally
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Is there any difference in regards to logic or processing if it was converted to:

```
function hello( $var )
{
    try
    {
        // do something with $var which may or may not throw an exception
        return $var;
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Please ignore the fact that nothing is done with the `$e` and ignore the simplicity/uselessness of the sample function; this is just an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The purpose of this conversion is to make the source code 100% compatible in PHP 5.3 because `finally{}` was introduced in 5.5 and I wish to make the minimum changes necessary while maintaining 100% of the logic.

I only ask because I personally have minimal experience using try/catch/finally blocks and I am not aware of all the gotchas.

Is there a better way to achieve PHP 5.3 compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you put a `return` in a finally statement then it will always be run after try has completed. Your first example (probably cut down) is going to use the result returned from the finally clause, not the try clause.

Your second example is a little different because it's unclear how you define `$var`. If you have `$var = $this->throwsException('x');` and that line is where the exception is thrown, then `$var` will be undefined in your catch clause. If `$var` is already defined then the catch clause will be where you return from, assuming the try clause throws an exception.

If you need a PHP 5.3 safe version of a finally clause, I would do something like this:

```
$var = false;
try {
    $var = $this->doSomething();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    $var = $ex->getMessage();
}
return $var;
```

Comment: Hi, is "If you put a return in a finally statement then it will always be run after try has completed." valid given there's a `return` in the `try{}` block? I've done some testing which disproves your claim. As for the confusion with `$var`'s origin; it is provided in the function declaration as a required parameter.

Comment: Yes it is valid

Comment: I'm sorry but I am having a really hard time applying what you've written to what I've asked. Can you show an example of an execution path which would have different results in which `finally{}` and `catch(){}` are the only differences?

Comment: Of course, give me a couple of hours :-) (AFK right now)

Comment: No problem, do note the `return $var;` in both the try and finally/catch blocks.

Comment: Finally takes precedence over try: https://eval.in/1059438, finally takes precedence over catch: https://eval.in/1059439, catching exception: https://eval.in/1059440 - hope this helps. I can write more examples tomorrow if the answer is still unclear